# Is mysql host without a user normal?

Tags: mysql

Is this normal under any circumstance? (host without a user) or

Does this indicate users have been removed but some info that corresponds to those users was left behind? or

Something else like I've been hacked?

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+--------------+-------------+
| user         | host        |
+--------------+-------------+
| root         | 127.0.0.1   |
| toasty       | 192.168.1.3 |
| toasty       | 192.168.1.4 |
|              | localhost   |
| root         | localhost   |
| tim          | localhost   |
| toastermaker | localhost   |
|              | newduck2    |
| root         | newduck2    |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for straightening it up

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html):

> If the User value is blank, it matches any user name.

In other words, it is perfectly normal, and you may think of empty value as `*`: matches any user name.

Comment: Thank you MySQL for the inconsistency. `'%'` for any host; `''` for any user.

Comment: Thanks, I'm off to find out how to tun it off (do away with "any user")